# FireFox appears to not support IFrame Data URIs

Tags: html, firefox, iframe

When I try to load a PDF Data URI into an iframe (eg, `src="data:application/pdf;base64,..."`) in FireFox (18.0.2 [current release], OSX) it instead opens a download window.

For an example, check out the website [JSPDF.com](http://jspdf.com/#)

[image]

The same site works fine in Aurora (20.0a2)

Is this a known issue with  Firefox? Is it not conforming to the spec...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aurora has a built-in PDF renderer that can render PDFs inline.

Current release as of yesterday does not have that; it first appears in Firefox 19, which is about to be released.

A browser without a PDF plug-in or built-in PDF renderer will simply offer to download or open in a helper app a PDF that's loaded in a window as you're doing, which is exactly what you see.

As far as the spec goes, both behaviors are compliant.  Nothing says a browser needs to support inline rendering of PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the options :

[image]

To :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with Firefox, iframes and data URIs. I resolved it by checking that there was no spaces in the data type definition. Mine was text/html, so instead of writing this:

```
src="data: text/html, ..."
```

it had to go like this:

```
src="data:text/html,..."
```

I conclude that firefox didn't understand the content type with spaces, thus considering it was a downloadable file.

Answer (score -1):

This might be caused when there is no adobe reader installed. I'm not sure though. As I can't test it here as I don't have a Mac with Firefox running.

Comment: It works with Firefox 20.a2 (Aurora), as stated in the post, so I doubt that's the cause.